# Export multiple files to csv from DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a following problem:
In my folder I have about 100 .uscd files. Each file contains 4 Tables (A, B, C and D).

I can open each file in DB Browser for SQLite via file - open database. Then I select table A and I can save this table as CSV.

But is there a way how to save tables A from all 100 files into CSV? That is not separately for each file?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could write a program that does that...

Comment: ok, but is there a way how to do that in DB Browser for SQLite?

Comment: No, DB Browser has no macro facility, which is what you would need to do that.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks! Do you have any tip what software can help me to solve my problem?